# Sort long length numbers by value in PHP (parts of half-numeric strings)

Tags: php, sorting, numeric

I have some strings begining with numbers and currently PHP's default `sort()` is handling it diffirently than I expect.

Current sorting results:

```
111a
112a
1123a
204a
205a
20765a
3a
```

My expectations:

```
3a
111a
112a
204a
205a
1123a
20765a
```

Should I for example all elements with all elements extracting the number at first? How I could do that in PHP in easy way?

Comment: If you know how many chars got numbers or text we can do something... otherwise we can do something... however what have you done so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use another PHP function called `natsort()` ;)

So, in your case:

```
$temp = array(
    '111a',
    '112a',
    '1123a',
    '204a',
    '205a',
    '20765a',
    '3a',
);
natsort($temp);
var_dump($temp);
```